# C# how to call files relative address rather absolute address

Tags: c#, file

I have found myself having to rely on having to use some local folders. No problem normally, but the main issue is that if transfer the project to another machine, even during development the structure reports back an error.

The error is that is page can't be displayed on a local website and an IO error when I go to read from the file.

The directory is as follows

```
C:\Users\Keith\OneDrive\Documents\Project 2016\Lingerie\Lingerie\Corset\Corset
```

The folders in question are

- Master Audio
- Images
- User Audio

[image: File Location]

The actual folder as they're used

```
private String folderPlay = @"C:\Users\Keith\OneDrive\Documents\Project 2016\Lingerie\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\Master Audio\";
private String folderRecord = @"C:\Users\Keith\OneDrive\Documents\Project 2016\Lingerie\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\User Audio\";
private String folderImages = @"C:\Users\Keith\OneDrive\Documents\Project 2016\Lingerie\Lingerie\Corset\Corset\Images\";
```

What I would like to do is be able to call those file relative to the code? Also if it's not too much trouble could a small note be attached so I can understand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only the path in your project rather than whole physical path

```
private String folderPlay = @"~/Master Audio";
private String folderRecord = @"~/User Audio";
private String folderImages = @"~/Images";
```

and my suggestion is use path like `Master_Audio`, `User_Audio`. Don't put space between word

Answer (score 0):

What I found useful in similar situation is to actually inject content root dir to the class that needs to know the location of particular resources:

E.g.

```
class Foo{

    private string readonly _contentRoot;

    public Foo (string contentRoot)
    {
        _contentRoot = contentRoot
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithImage()
    {
        string imgRelativePath = "/img/img1.png";
        string imgPath = Path.Combine(_contentRoot, imgRelativePath);

        // do something with imgPath        
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is that you can now write tests for your methods (which might be difficult otherwise). Sometimes unit testing framework copies libs to a temp location, but you still want to run the tests.

You can resolve root directory from several locations, depending how you run the code:

- For unit tests, use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`
- For Web app `HttpRuntime` or `HttpContext`
- For Windows app `AppDomain.BaseDirectory` or similar

Rule of thumb:

- You should not have any hardcoded absolute paths (pain with testing, running on another machine, deployment)
- Instead, use relative paths (usually relative to project root or root/content)